# liveagent.init callback function

Tags: javascript, liveagent, deployment-api

I am trying to setup liveagent but am running into an issue with starting the chat.

We have a form that the user enters information about themselves, and then a button to begin the chat.

I use the information entered to add Custom Details to the console and init liveagent. Once this has happened I then call liveagent.startChat().

This call is throwing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startChat' of undefined

This is most likely because liveagent.init() hasn't completed, but liveagent doesn't return a value and has no callback function.

How can I wait until liveagent.init() has complete without manually setting a timeout?

Chat button

```
<a href="#" class="fona-button" id="liveagent_button_online_{!buttonId}" onclick="chat()">Chat With Us</a>
```

onclick function

```
function chat() {
        var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
        var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var endApp = $('#endApp').val();

        var cleanPhone = '';

        if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !endApp) {
            alert('Please fill all form fields');
        } else {
            cleanPhone = phone.match(/\d+/g)[0];
            liveagent.setName(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('FirstName', firstName);
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('LastName', lastName);
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('Email', email);
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('Phone', phone);
            liveagent.addCustomDetail('End Application', endApp);
            liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact')
                .map('LastName', 'LastName', true, true, false)
                .map('Phone', 'Phone', true, true, false)
                .map('Email', 'Email', true, true, false);
            liveagent.init('{!url}/chat', '{!deploymentId}', '{!organizationId}');
            if (!window._laq) { 
                window._laq = []; 
            }
            window._laq.push(function(){
                liveagent.showWhenOnline('{!buttonId}', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_{!buttonId}'));
                liveagent.showWhenOffline('{!buttonId}', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_{!buttonId}'));
            });
            liveagent.startChat('{!buttonId}');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, every time I got that error was because the method

```
liveagent.showWhenOnline('YOUR_ID_HERE', document.getElementById('your_element'));
```

was using one ID and then, the

```
onclick="liveagent.startChat('YOUR_ID_HERE')"
```

was using a different ID. Try to make sure you have the same ID on both places.